Show that $\frac{\text{quadratic}}{\text{quadratic}}$ with no common factors is many-to-one
Let
$${f(x)=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx^2+ex+f}}$$
hence,
$${f'(x)= \frac{(2ax+b)(dx^2+ex+f)-(2dx+e)(ax^2+bx+c)}{(dx^2+ex+f)^2}}.$$
If $f$ is not a continuously decreasing or increasing function then it is many-to-one.
Therefore,on simplifying sign of $f'(x)$, this depends on the sign of expression
$${(ae-db)x^2 +2(af-dc)x+(bf-ec)}.$$
Hence, if
${(af-dc) ^2-(bf-ec) (ae-db) <0 }$
and ${ae \neq db}$
then $f$ is one-to-one.
So we want to show that these two conditions must not be satisfied simultaneously, but I don't know how to show that, or is there another simpler way to prove this.

My book says that a quadratic by quadratic function with no common factors is always a many-to-one function.


The statement that ,"a quadratic by quadratic function with no common factors is always a many-one function" is given in my book and i am unsure of its validity, although it holds true for all of the functions i have seen.

If $ae=db$, your inequality reduces to $(something)^2<0$

As a different issue, your first step assumes that the funciton you're dealing with is continuous over $\mathbb R$ - but this is not always the case. I would suggest a different strategy. First, if the denominator has zeros, what happens near those zeros? Second, if the denominator is irreducible, what happens to the limits to $\pm \infty$?

Here is a sketch of the proof.
If the denominator has two different zeros, $x_{1, 2}$, and since by hypothesis it shares no factors with the numerator, then near those zeros the function behaves like $\frac 1 {x-x_{1,2}}$, having a vertical asymptote and going to $+\infty$ on one side of the asymptote and to $-\infty$ on the other side. Having two such asymptotes necessarily means that the function is not injective.
If the denominator has a single zero with multiplicity two, the limits from the left and the right are both $+\infty$ or both $-\infty$. Again, this implies that the function is not injective.
Finally, if the denominator is irreducible, then the function is continuous over all of $\mathbb R$.
The limits for $x \to \pm \infty$ are equal (to $\frac ad$ in your notation), but the function is not constant. Pick any point $x_0$ where the function is not equal to $\frac ad$: to the right and to the left of this point, the function tends to $\frac ad$ and so must touch every value between $f(x_0)$ and $\frac ad$. Therefore it cannot be injective.

I see that my answer is basically the same as yours.  I was midway through writing my when your answer was posted.  Do you think I should delete mine or leave it as is?

I woudl say to leave it. Two different explanations are better than one, and I'd hate to have you waste your effort.

Have you seen my answer ?

(we assume that $a$ and $d$ are both non-zero).
Instead of letter $f$, which is already used as a coefficient, I will set :
$$\varphi(x)=y=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx^2+ex+f} \tag{1}$$
We want to prove that $\varphi$ is non-injective. For that we are going to work on a simpler function. Indeed, Euclidean division of the numerator by the denominator of $\varphi(x)$ gives :
$$\varphi(x)=\frac{a}{d}+\frac{gx+h}{dx^2+ex+f}=\frac{a}{d}+\frac{g}{d}.\underbrace{\frac{x+h'}{x^2+e'x+f'}}_{\psi(x)}\tag{2}$$
Therefore, as $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are affine transforms one of the other, proving the non-injectivity of $\varphi$ is equivalent to prove the non-injectivity of $\psi$.
(we will drop the "primes" in $\psi$ now on).
The key idea is to transform equality $\psi(x_1)=\psi(x_2)$ under the following form :
$$\underbrace{\frac{x_1+h}{x_1^2+e x_1+f}}_{\psi(x_1)}=\underbrace{\frac{x_2+h}{x_2^2+e x_2+f}}_{\psi(x_2)}=\frac{(x_1-x_2)}{(x_1^2-x_2^2)+(x_1-x_2)e}\tag{3}$$
Comment : the second inequality comes from a classical result : if $\tfrac{N_1}{D_1}=\tfrac{N_2}{D_2}$ then $\tfrac{N_1}{D_1}=\tfrac{N_2}{D_2}=\tfrac{pN_1+qN_2}{pD_1+qD_2}$.
(3) gives :
$$\frac{x_1+h}{x_1^2+e x_1+f}=\frac{1}{x_1+x_2+e} \tag{4}$$
From (4), one can "extract", for a given $x_1$ :
$$x_2=\underbrace{\frac{-h x_1+(f-eh)}{x_1+h}}_{t(x_1)}\tag{5}$$
$x_2$ being in general different from $x_1$, the non-injectivity of $\psi$ is established (two different points having the same image : this function is broadly speaking $2$-to-$1$).
Please note that transformation $t$ connecting $x_2$ and $x_1$ is a homographic transformation.
See graphical representation below (Geogebra) :

Fig. 1 : The case without vertical asymptotes (denominator of $\psi(x)$ with no real roots). The two other cases (one or two vertical asymptotes) have the same kind of representation.
The fact that the two values giving the same image are related by a homographic transform isn't so surprizing when considering cubic curve $\varpsi$ in the context of projective geometry.

If the denominator has distinct roots $x_1$, $x_2$ then we have
$$R(x) = \gamma + \frac{\alpha_1}{x-t_1} + \frac{\alpha_2}{x-t_2}$$
There are two subcases, $x_1$, $x_2$ are real ( and so are the $\alpha_i$'s),  or $x_1$, $x_2$ are non-real and complex conjugate ( so $\alpha_2 = \bar \alpha_1$).

The real case:   Assume $x_1< x_2$. Now look at the signs of $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$.  We'll skip the interesting details.

The complex case:  it can be reduced with a linear change of variable


$$R(x) = \frac{x + q}{x^2+1}$$
and its derivative has two simple zeros, so again $R(x)$ not injective.
If the denominator has equal roots, we can reduce to
$$R(x) = \frac{x+q}{x^2}$$
and this is not injective around $0$
Note: there exists injective rational functions, for instance $x + \frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

The proposition is false if we allow $d=0$
Assuming $d\ne 0$
The denominator can have no real roots, one root (with multiplicity) or 2 distinct roots.
If the denominator has no roots, the function is continuous and $\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty} = \lim_\limits{x\to \infty} = \frac ad.$  In which case the function has a max/min.
If the denominator has one root with multiplicity then there is a vertical asymptote at this root.  And both on the left and the right the function is going to the same extreme.
If the function has 2 distinct roots, then approaching each asymptote from the left and right gives 4 places where the function is going to infinity or negative infinity, and if we are 1-1 we can only have 2 places where we go to $\pm \infty$
